# Please reconsider your vote to close for this question about inappropriate jokes in the workplace

Tags: discussion

[How can I tell a coworker to stop making awkward sexual jokes?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/20846/how-can-i-tell-a-coworker-to-stop-making-awkward-sexual-jokes)

This question has had a few edits to clean it up.  It seems on-topic and could potentially be useful to others in the future.  In light of these changes will you please reconsider your vote to close?

Thanks!

Comment: Wow that question close log is interesting with two moderators being the first two close votes, prior to their diamond...

Comment: It should be closed because I expected to hear some good jokes when I clicked on it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the perfectly valid points about it being duplicated; that closed question is *super old* and it already has an *accepted answer*.

Even if it meets the minimum requirements; what value could it possibly add at this point?

Comment: My bad.  I saw the edits and missed the date AND the answer.

Comment: I do that all the time

Comment: I think the op finished his internschip by now ^^

Answer (score 6):

While the question is no longer "unclear" as it was when it was closed, I see no reason to reopen it. As soon as it reopens, it would be (rightfully) closed as a duplicate.

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=sexual+jokes